# Discord.py Self Bot Get All User ID's

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My Source Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def logall(ctx, meesage):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  with open('logs.json', 'r') as file:
    user_list = json.load(file)
  members = await guild.fetch_members(limit=150).flatten()
  for member in members:
    user_list.append(member.id)
  with open('logs.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(user_list, file)
  print('Logged All Users!')
```

I have used different ways to get user ID's and none of them actually got all User ID's for any server.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JasonTorrez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\JasonTorrez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JasonTorrez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

I am trying to be able to gather User ID's from any server I join.

Comment: Use `ctx.guild`

Comment: Doesn't get all User ID's in any given server either only get's my ID or little to none of the user ID's in the given server.

Comment: does the bot have full permissions?

Comment: You need full permission to get userids?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py rewrite get\_member() function returning None for all users except bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221377/discord-py-rewrite-get-member-function-returning-none-for-all-users-except-bot)

Answer (score 2):

Discord disabled that feature for selfbots, unless your accounts has permission to kick/ban members in a server. You now require something called an intent, which you can't get as a selfbot.