# discord py, ctx.guild.members, only returns bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

`ctx.guild.members`

is an array which is supposed to return every member in the server the command was called from but if i do

`print(ctx.guild.members)`

it only returns the bot itself

`[<Member id=769576973214547969 name='test bot' discriminator='2461' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=768187276873957437 name='test server' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=4>>]`

im trying to meet the quality standards which is why its worded long and not to the point

Comment: This should fix your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64221473/13927032

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are like permissions, you have to define it to use some things like getting members, channels etc.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix = '', intents=intents)
```

For more information about Intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).