# ctx.guild.members is not retrieving the members of a guild, just returning the bot name even with discord.Intents

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with discord.py, and I want to retrieve a list of all of the members in the guild. To do this I used `ctx.guild.members`. However, when I ran the program it only returned the bot's name and id.

So I looked at this question: [discord py, ctx.guild.members, only returns bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518536/discord-py-ctx-guild-members-only-returns-bot), which said to use the `.Intents()` method to add permissions for the bot to retrieve the members of the server.

So I wrote this code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()

bot = Bot("e? ")
client2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "e? ", intents = intents)

@bot.command(name = "work")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def work(ctx):
  if os.path.exists("users.txt") == False:
    f = open("users.txt", "x")
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
      print(user)
    print(len(ctx.guild.members))
```

Even with these intents, the bot is still returning only the name of the bot, not the other members in the server.

And this is what `ctx.guild.members` is returning:

```
[<Member id=916863469582712863 name='Excelsior' discriminator='3908' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=983934859091279872 name='thing' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=4>>]
```

Since it says the `member_count` is 4 (which it is), I thought the bot didn't have the permissions to retrieve the details of the users in the server. So I went to the discord bot developer portal, and went to URL Generator, and selected the following:

[image: image showing what I selected]

When I select `guilds.members.read`, it asks me to enter a redirect url in order for me to add it to a server. However I don't know what url to add in order for the bot to have the permissions, and I don't even know if what I'm doing to solve the problem is going to solve it.

How do I get the bot to show a list of all the members in the server?

---

Here are the questions I've already taken a look at:

[Discord Bot - Guild Members Showing in count... but not in guild.members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397965/discord-bot-guild-members-showing-in-count-but-not-in-guild-members):

I enabled the intents in the "Bot" section of the portal, as shown below:

[image: Bot section of portal]

However, it still only returned the bots name, not all of the members.

[discord py, ctx.guild.members, only returns bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518536/discord-py-ctx-guild-members-only-returns-bot):

I applied this to my code as shown above in the question, but it still only returned the bots name.

The version of discord.py is 1.7.3.

Comment: Are you using this code on a `TextChannel` to which your bot doesn't have access/permissions? I think you need to enable the message content intent in your Discord Developer Portal and that there's no need for the `guilds.members.read` 'scope' (I've not tried changing/adding scopes, but everything, probably code which doesn't need them has worked fine for me). Also, you're writing to a file (and not appending etc.), meaning it is overwritten every time; your bot is probably the last member. But you're getting the guild's members and not a text channel's, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: maybe if you try to make the role of your bot as the top most role in the server it may work

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder thanks for your comment. I’ll try enabling the messages.read scope, but then what redirect url do I enter? I know how to enter one but what do I enter? Also ive tried printing it in a for loop and it only returns the bot so the file overwriting is not a problem (as of now). I’ll try ur advice though, thanks!

Comment: @ShwetaK I tried giving the bot admin role but it still didn't work unfortunately. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: For improved readability, `discord.Intents.all()` is preferred as it's a classmethod. You can also view `guild.member_count` rather than getting the length of the members (with the added bonus of not needing the intents).

Comment: @10Rep, no- what I meant was that's probably not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I made a mistake in the code. I had to add intents to the variable which was actually running my bot with the token. So,

```py
intents = discord.Intents().all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "e? ", intents = intents)
client2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "e? ", intents = intents)

bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Thanks to [TheFungusAmongUs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245648/chat-for-https-stackoverflow-com-q-72624777-16177247) for their help!

Comment: Extra question: why do you need two bots? You shouldn't be running both of them at the same time.